# How to display the parent taxonomy term of the "Tags" field?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, 9

On my Drupal 9 site, I created taxonomy terms in the "tags" vocabulary (the vocabulary and the default field of the "article" content type) :

[image]

When I create a node, I select a taxonomy term in the form (for example "ICO"). The node displays the "tags" field :

[image]

I want that if the node has the term "ICO", it also displays the parent terms. Like this :

> Catégories : Culture geek, crypto, ICO

How can I do this? I did not find anything in the view mode regarding this field.

Comment: Did you come across this contrib? https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis It works thank you

Comment: Lovely, it would be great to post what worked for you here as an answer, to assist others that land here with the same question.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I cannot answer my own question. You must make an answer and I validate it

Comment: sorry, thought you could. I will post one in the next couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a field formatter for that, luckily there is one already that covers this use case, it's the [Hierarchical Term Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter) that works with Drupal 9.

1. For the given taxonomy structure:

[image]

2. By selecting the terminal term (in this example 'jodri')

[image]

3. Installing the [Hierarchical Term Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter), with its default configuration

[image]

4. Results in the following display of the rendered node.

[image]